# How can I get a bottom TabBar on React Native (Android) with React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I do like this https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/801
but it's can't work , it's always on top (Android)

How i can do to move TabBar to bottom of screen

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Feed: {
    screen: FeedStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarLabel: 'Module',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
    },
  },
  Min: {
    screen: Min,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarLabel: 'Min',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
    },
  },

  max: {
    screen: max,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      tabBarLabel: 'max',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
    },
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The general Api for TabNavigator is TabNavigator(RouteConfigs, TabNavigatorConfig). TabNavigatorConfig has various options one of them is tabBarPosition which takes 'top' or 'bottom'. Default is 'top' for android so change it to 'bottom' as shown below.

Check [React-Navigation Tab docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab)

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: FeedStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarLabel: 'Module',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },
    Min: {
      screen: Min,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarLabel: 'Min',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },

    max: {
      screen: max,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarLabel: 'max',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon namax="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
      },
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
  }
);
```